# Fill width in a Pane

Tags: java, layout, javafx

There is a `Pane` as root and a `GridPane` as its child. The root resizes with the stage. How can I achieve that the `GridPane` gets **automatically** resized with the root to fill the width? **Any width should possible.** Is it possible without property binding?

This is the situation:

1. A `Pane` **root** (yellow) is the root of the `Scene` so it fills the width and height of the `Stage`.
2. A `GridPane` (green) with one row and 3 colums as child of **root**.
3. The row should have a fixed height.
4. The first and third column should have a constant size
5. The middle column should grow to maximum
6. The `GridPane` should fill the width of its parent

Unfortunately the `GridPane` does not fill the width:
[image: GridPane should fill the width of its parent]

Code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // Resizes with the stage
    final Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");

    // grid: 1 row, 3 colums
    // should have a constant height and should grow in width to fill parent pane
    final GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    root.getChildren().add(gridPane);
    gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
    gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);

    final RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints(100); // constant height = 100
    final ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints(100, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
    // should grow as much as possible in width
    final ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints(200, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    final ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints(100, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
    gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(row);
    gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col2, col3);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(600);
    primaryStage.setHeight(400);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The size of nodes inside panes is controlled by the way the individual pane implements its layout: i.e. the size of a node is effectively determined by its parent. So the overall size of your grid pane is controlled by the layout implementation of `Pane`.

`Pane` actually does minimal layout work: it effectively just positions everything at (0,0) and sizes it to its preferred size. So your grid pane gets its preferred width, which is the sum of the preferred widths of the columns.

So to get your grid pane to grow, you either need to change its preferred width, or use a layout pane that allows you to control how it grows.

For example:

```
gridPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
```

will make the grid pane grow to the width of root. This will just add extra space to the right of all three columns, so additionally setting

```
col2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
```

will let `col2` have the extra width.

Alternatively, using an `AnchorPane` for `root`:

```
// Pane root = new Pane();
AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
```

and setting

```
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(gridPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(gridPane, 0.0);
```

(again with the `col2` `hgrow` set) will have the same effect.

Or you could do

```
VBox root = new VBox();
root.setFillWidth(true);
```

(for example: there are many solutions).

The choice of solution depends on what other nodes, if any, you have inside the root pane.

Answer (score 3):

`Pane` does not automatically layouts its children. Try to use `VBox` instead. It will fill the width of available space by (if possible) resizing its childdren. This way the GridPane will resize on stage width changes.

Now, you can manage the gridpane columns how they share the space. According to your description it is enough to set

```
col2.setHgrow( Priority.ALWAYS );
```

Answer (score 3):

To make gridpane automatically adjust use the fxml. Don't do it with the java.

See below they are set to a percentage width. The very last row in my example below has fixed settings.

```
<GridPane fx:id="gridPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">

  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="50" /> 
    <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="50" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints percentHeight="35" />
    <RowConstraints percentHeight="35" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="106.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="106.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually your result is the expected `100 + 200 + 100 = 400px`:

```
final ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints(100, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
//                                                   ↑
final ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints(200, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
//                                                   ↑
final ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints(100, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
//                                                   ↑
```

And you define:

```
primaryStage.setWidth(600);
```

Just change medium column to fill the remainin `200px`

```
final ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints(100, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
final ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints(400, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
//                                                   ↑ change to 400
final ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints(100, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be answer for a constant width of root. But I'd want that the GridPane grows dynamically in width. So it should work with any width.